# Creating a std::string from std::string_view

Tags: c++, string, string-view

Given a `string_view sv` and a `string s(sv)`, does `s` use the same char array internally as `sv`? Is it safe to say that when `s` is destroyed, `sv` is still valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a `std::string` object *always* copies (or moves, if it can) the string, and handles its own memory internally.

For your example, the strings handled by `sv` and `s` are totally different and separate.

Answer (score 1):

Just run this demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#inc,lude <string_view>

int main()
{
    const char *s = "Hello World!";

    std::cout << "The address of the string literal is "
        << static_cast< const void * >( s ) << '\n';

    std::string_view sv( s );

    std::cout << "The address of the object of the type std::string_view is "
        << static_cast< const void * >( sv.data() ) << '\n';

    std::string ss( sv );

    std::cout << "The address of the string is "
        << static_cast< const void * >( ss.data() ) << '\n';
}
```

Its output might look like

```
The address of the string literal is 00694E6C
The address of the object of the type std::string_view is 00694E6C
The address of the string is 0133F7C0
```

As you can see the address of the string literal is the same as the address of the memory returned by the data member `data` of the object of `std::string_view`.

That is the class `std::string_view` is just a wrapper around the underlined referenced object.

As for the class `std::string` then it creates its one copy of a string usually stored in the allocated memory.

For example you may not change an object of the type `std::string_view` but `std::string` is designed specially that process stored strings.

The suffix `view` in the class name `std::string_view` means that you can only view the underlined object to which an object of the type `std::string_view` refers.